# Migration Command to import table daa in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-artisan

By using migration I am able to import the database structure of a Laravel website. But what is the best and correct way to import its data as well.

Is there any command available in migration?

Need help. I am using Laravel 7.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at Seeder https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding

Comment: Are you trying to migrate an existing database to your laravel application, or initialize some data, or create fake testing data?

Comment: @kurt Friars: migrating an existing db.

Comment: What kind of DB is it? This is not a laravel specific problem. You should look at the best way to migrate data for your DB. ie) dump + restore

Comment: I have an application of Laravel made by another developer . He give me the complete code and I have seen the migration files in it. There is no db script in it. If I run migration then db structure imported successfully but there is no data in tables. All tables are empty. What can I do to import the database with tables + data.

Comment: @EBDEV This is not a laravel specific problem. You should look at the best way to migrate data for your DB. ie) dump + restore

Comment: @Kurt Friars: After I complete my work of Laravel I will handover the application to another developer. Can I give him full db dumbs in sql form. So that he can import the db easily? Is migration does not give any feature to import/export data?

Comment: Did you google anything at all, or try to solve your problem on your own? Search [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+db+dump+restore&oq=laravel+db+dump+restore&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4725j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for "laravel db dump restore ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is common when you have to migrate a table with its data to other project like Laravel.

**Proposed Solution**

1. Dump the data of table you want to migrate to a `.sql` file and place that file some where in the folder you can access it. For ease let place the file inside `public` folder.
2. Make a command to import that `.sql` file.
3. Make a seeder and call that command in `run function`.

**Implementation Guidance**

*Make a command*

`php artisan make:command ImportXTable`

This command will create a new command class in the app/Console/Commands directory.

After generating your command,goto `app/Console/Commands` directory and open the file you have just created i.e ImportXTable, you should fill in the signature and description properties of the class, which will be used when displaying your command on the list screen. The handle method will be called when your command is executed. You may place your command logic in this method.

***Sample Script***

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ImportXTable extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'import:xtable';//this is what you will call  to import table

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Import the .sql file for ImportXTable';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $sql = public_path('fileNameToImport.sql');// write the sql filename here to import
        
        
        DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($sql));
    }
}
```

Then in `kernel.php` in the `commands` array register your command as follows

```
  protected $commands = [
        Commands\ImportXTable::class,
    ];
```

**Seeder Implementation**

*Make a Seeder for Xtable and Call that command in seeder as follows*

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class XTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        \Artisan::call('import:xtable');//calling the command to import data from .sql file to database table
    }
}
```

Now when ever you run your seeder the file will be imported from dump sql to your table.

***Remember to configure your sql file to get imported to your desired table and keep the name of table same, or you can edit .sql file in editor***

*For Example You can Edit your Sql file and wrote this*

```
insert  into `x_table`(`column_name1`,`column_name2`,`column_name3`) values 

(0,16777215,'-','-'),
............
```

Comment: thats what i am looking for. Let me implement this and then I will get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EBDEV implement this method and let me know, and if it helped mark it accepted so it can help others too.

Comment: Sure. One thing confuses me is : after I copy the laravel project folder in my local pc, do I need to run the migrate command or not. Because if I run the migrate command like : php artisan migrate then it will generate the structures of tables but it will not contain any data. After that when I will  run your code implementation then it will trigger the SQL file which already has code to create db structure with data. As db structure is already created through migration then it will give error in this case. So can I skip migration command?

Comment: @EBDEV edit your sql file and remove the structure creation code. The sql file should contain only data for insertion code like this ```insert  into `x_table`(`column_name1`,`column_name2`,`column_name3`) values 

(0,16777215,'-','-'),
............```

Comment: ok I can do this. But  I wondered that there is no built in functionality like migration in laravel which stores the table data also?